# How to prove Generalized DeMorgan's Laws

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

[Assignment Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnTZt.png)

I have an assignment due tomorrow and I am beyond stuck on this problem, this course was poorly organized and we are lacking in understanding of a lot of material. We never learned mathematical induction so I'm lost in the wind.

I know how to use Kalish Montegue derivations and sort of figured out I need to somehow prove that (Pi/..Pn)<-->!(!Pi/..!Pn) and likewise (Pi/..Pn)<-->!(!Pi/..!Pn) from how the question was set up but no clue on how to start or how to use the induction.

Any pointers would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you have show that $\neg(A\circ B)=\neg A\bullet \neg B$ for any $A,B$, then if you assume that $\neg(P_1\circ\ldots\circ P_n)=\neg P_1\bullet\ldots\bullet\neg P_n$, what may you infer about $\neg(P_1\circ\ldots\circ P_n\circ P_{n+1})$?